# How do I get my Pickers to work correctly?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I have been reading up on pickers and wanted to try and get a simple one working, but I do not know what I am doing wrong with my code.

I have assigned my pickers in my storyboard to the correct controllers. I then added the following to my header.

```
@interface CustomerView : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIPickerView * CompanyPicker;
IBOutlet UIPickerView * ClientPicker;
    NSMutableArray *arrayCompanies;
NSMutableArray *arrayClients;
}
```

I then added some info to the arrays I created in my heading under didload:

```
  arrayCompanies = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [arrayCompanies addObject:@"Test Company 01"];
  [arrayCompanies addObject:@"Test Company 02"];
  [arrayCompanies addObject:@"Test Company 03"];
  [arrayCompanies addObject:@"Test Company 04"];
  [arrayCompanies addObject:@"Test Company 05"];
  [arrayCompanies addObject:@"Test Company 06"];
  [arrayCompanies addObject:@"Test Company 07"];

  arrayClients   = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  [arrayClients addObject:@"Test Client 01"];
  [arrayClients addObject:@"Test Client 01"];
  [arrayClients addObject:@"Test Client 01"];
  [arrayClients addObject:@"Test Client 01"];
  [arrayClients addObject:@"Test Client 01"];
  [arrayClients addObject:@"Test Client 01"];
  [arrayClients addObject:@"Test Client 01"];
```

After that I added the following in the implementation, but the info is not seeming to load into my arrays. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

  return 2;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {

return [arrayCompanies count];
  return [arrayClients count];
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

return [arrayCompanies objectAtIndex:row];
    return [arrayClients objectAtIndex:row];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component {

NSLog(@"Selected Company: %@. Index of selected company: %i", [arrayCompanies objectAtIndex:row], row);
  NSLog(@"Selected Client: %@. Index of selected client: %i", [arrayClients objectAtIndex:row], row);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this technique:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {

  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
if ([thePickerView isEqual: CompanyPicker]) {
 return [arrayCompanies count];
} else if ([thePickerView isEqual: ClientPicker]) {
  return [arrayClients count];
}
 return 0;

}
```

Comment: also

return [arrayCompanies count];

return [arrayClients count]; // this line is never run

Comment: I have tried that and while my application does not see any errors, when I run it to see if my pickers are there, it bombs out :( Anything else I am missing? It says *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView numberOfComponentsInPickerView:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a773b0'

Comment: This indicates that your UIPickerView is actually initialized as a UIView and not a UIPickerView in your nib file. You should make sure in StoryBoard that you are setting the UIView to be a UIPickerView.

Comment: Thanks Joel, you were right. I hadn't realized that was causing it to bomb out. Where did your answer go? I wanted to select it as the right one :)

Comment: My answer didn't account for you having two separate pickers. So NeverBe had the correct answer. If you want you can up vote my comment that helped with your IBOutlet problem.